# Is it possible to build an admin website using Firebase Admin SDK with Angular2

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-admin

I'm working on a mobile application which uses Firebase for backend and now I'm going to implement an admin website using Angular2 and host it on Firebase hosting so I want to know that is it possible to use Firebase Admin SDK with Angular2. And if not, is there any solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase Admin SDK is designed to run server side and not client side. So you can use any webfrontend in combination with the Firebase Admin SDK but you have to develop your custom interface between your webfrontend and your server side code (e.g. you have to create your own rest services)